# Looping through an array based on the first index

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, indexing

I have two arrays and I am wanting to loop through a second array to only return arrays whose first element is equal to an element from another array.

```
 a = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
 b = [[9, 23, 45, 67, 56, 23, 54], [10, 8, 52, 30, 15, 47, 109], [11, 81, 
 152, 54, 112, 78, 167], [13, 82, 84, 63, 24, 26, 78], [18, 182, 25, 63, 96, 
 104, 74]]
```

I have two different arrays, a and b. I would like to find a way to look through each of the sub-arrays(?) within b in which
the first value is equal to the values in array a to create a new array, c.

The result I am looking for is:

```
  c = [[10, 8, 52, 30, 15, 47, 109],[11, 81, 152, 54, 112, 78, 167],[13, 82, 84, 63, 24, 26, 78]]
```

Does Python have a tool to do this in a way Excel has MATCH()?

I tried looping in a manner such as:

```
 for i in a:
      if i in b:
          print (b)
```

But because there are other elements within the array, this way is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Further explanation of the problem:

a = [5, 6, 7, 9, 12]

I read in a excel file using XLRD (b_csv_data):

```
 Start  Count   Error   Constant    Result1 Result2 Result3 Result4
 5       41       0       45             23      54      66       19
 5.4     44       1       21             52      35       6       50
 6       16       1       42             95      39       1       13
 6.9     50       1       22             71      86      59       97
 7       38       1       43             50      47      83       67
  8      26       1       29             100     63      15       40
 9       46       0       28             85       9      27       81
 12      43       0       21             74      78      20       85
```

Next, I created a look to read in a select number of rows. For simplicity, this file above only has a few rows. My current file has about 100 rows.

```
for r in range (1, 7): #skipping headers and only wanting first few rows to start

     b_raw = b_csv_data.row_values(r) 
     b = np.array(b_raw) # I created this b numpy array from the line of code above
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) -

```
In [8]: b[np.isin(b[:,0],a)]
Out[8]: 
array([[ 10,   8,  52,  30,  15],
       [ 11,  81, 152,  54, 112],
       [ 13,  82,  84,  63,  24]])
```

With sorted `a`, we can also use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(a,b[:,0])
idx[idx==len(a)] = 0
out = b[a[idx] == b[:,0]]
```

If you have an array with different number of elements per row, which is essentially array of lists, you need to modify the slicing part. So, in that case, get the first off elements -

```
b0 = [bi[0] for bi in b]
```

Then, use `b0` to replace all instances of `b[:,0]` in earlier posted methods.

Comment: What if the arrays are different lengths as reflected in my edit?

Comment: @user11487335 Make sure the inputs, `a` and `b` are arrays. So, as pre-processing do - `a=np.array(a); b= np.array(b)`. I assumed arrays as the question stated so.

Comment: Correct. They are numpy arrays. Just applied those changes to make sure they are numpy arrays and the same error comes up :(. What is the significance of the line: idx[idx==len(a)] = 0. Is that specifically picking out the first index?

Comment: @user11487335 What's the shape of `a` and `b`? You can get those with `a.shape` and `b.shape`. Regarding the second searchsorted one, that `idx` is picking indices based on sorted matches and with that line `idx[idx==len(a)] = 0` getting rid of out of bounds ones.

Comment: a in my code is (75, ) and b is (22, ), (22, ), (22, ), (22, )

Comment: @user11487335 I was expecting `b's` shape to be a tuple of 2 elements. How come you are getting 4 tuples? How are you getting the shape? Are you doing `print(b.shape)`?

Comment: I have used XLRD to read in an excel file. I then created a loop to only read in a certain value of r rows. In this case, it is 4 rows each with 22 elements. My goal to to select rows only which the first element is in my a array.

Comment: @user11487335 I understand what your goal is. I am just not sure if that's a regular 2D array. So, I needed to get `print(b.shape)`.

Comment: It prints : (22,)
(22,)
(22,)
(22,) as a single column

Comment: @user11487335 Alright and what does `print(b.dtype)` say?

Comment: It prints float64 beneath each of the (22)'s

Comment: @user11487335 Please check out the edits at the end - `If you have an array with different number of elem...` part. Try that `b0` edit in the codes.

Comment: I get: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. When I searched this code, it is saying my b array is not iterable

Comment: @user11487335 Please add minimal reproducible sample data into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
c = [l for l in b if l[0] in a]
```

Output:

```
[[10, 8, 52, 30, 15], [11, 81, 152, 54, 112], [13, 82, 84, 63, 24]]
```

If your `list` or `array`s are considerably large, using `numpy.isin` can be significantly faster:

```
b[np.isin(b[:, 0], a), :]
```

Benchmark:

```
a = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
b = [[9, 23, 45, 67, 56], [10, 8, 52, 30, 15], [11, 81, 152, 54, 112], 
 [13, 82, 84, 63, 24], [18, 182, 25, 63, 96]]

list_comp, np_isin = [], []
for i in range(1,100):
    a_test = a * i
    b_test = b * i
    list_comp.append(timeit.timeit('[l for l in b_test if l[0] in a_test]', number=10, globals=globals()))
    a_arr = np.array(a_test)
    b_arr = np.array(b_test)
    np_isin.append(timeit.timeit('b_arr[np.isin(b_arr[:, 0], a_arr), :]', number=10, globals=globals()))
```

[image]

While it is not clear and concise, I would recommend using `list` comprehension if the `b` is shorter than 100. Otherwise, `numpy` is your way to go.

Comment: Even for numpy arrays?

Comment: @user11487335 Depends on the length of your lists or arrays. If they are of similar length as the examples, I would recommend using `list` than `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit in which they are not similar lengths. I like  the isin feature numpy has, but that only works for similar lengths?

Comment: @user11487335 The length of subarrays wouldn't matter that much. It is the length of `b` that matters the most. Take a look at the benchmark i've just posted :)

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but the benchmark alone makes this post worth it.

Comment: @Divakar Not sure about it either. Hope the downvoter could explain why :P

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it reverse. It is better to loop through the elements of b array and check if it is present in a. If yes then print that element of b. See the answer below.

```
a = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
b = [[9, 23, 45, 67, 56, 23, 54], [10, 8, 52, 30, 15, 47, 109], [11, 81, 152, 54, 112, 78, 167], [13, 82, 84, 63, 24, 26, 78], [18, 182, 25, 63, 96, 104, 74]]

for bb in b:  # if you want to check only the first element of b is in a
    if bb[0] in a:
            print(bb)

for bb in b:   # if you want to check if any element of b is in a
    for bbb in bb:
        if bbb in a:
            print(bb)
```

Output:

```
[10, 8, 52, 30, 15, 47, 109]
[11, 81, 152, 54, 112, 78, 167]
[13, 82, 84, 63, 24, 26, 78]
```

Comment: I tried applying this technique in mode code, but the output was IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. My b array is being reproduced by reading in an excel file through XLRD. I then created a loop to read only the first few rows as I am currently working with several hundred rows.  With those few rows I have read in, I want to select only the rows whose first value is in the a array.